# UE4 C++ how to call method from UChildActorComponent?

Tags: c++, casting, unreal-engine4

```
UPROPERTY(Category=Weapon,EditAnywhere,meta=(AllowPrivateAccess="true"))
UChildActorComponent*ClientWeapon;

UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere,Category="Weapon")
TSubclassOf<AWeaponBaseClient> WeaponClientClass;

UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere,Category="Weapon")
TSubclassOf<AWeaponBaseServer> WeaponServerClass;

UPROPERTY(Category=Weapon,EditAnywhere,Replicated,meta=(AllowPrivateAccess="true"))
UChildActorComponent*ServerWeapon;
```

this is UChildActorComponent Create by headfile.

```
ClientWeapon->SetChildActorClass(WeaponClientClass);

ServerWeapon->SetChildActorClass(WeaponServerClass);

ClientWeapon->CreateChildActor();

ServerWeapon->CreateChildActor();
```

in cpp file,construction function,I initallize the UChildActorComponent.

now I need call function from ClientWeapon,can you tell me how to cast to ClientWeapon->GetChildActor?

Answer (score 0):

`ClientWeapon` is a `UChildActorComponent`.

To access your Actor, you need to get the Child Actor from the component and then cast it to your class

```
AActor* ChildActor = ClientWeapon->GetChildActor();

WeaponClientClass* WeaponActor = Cast<WeaponClientClass>(ChildActor);

if (WeaponActor != nullptr) {
 // Now you can use your Weapon Actor
}
```